# KnockOut ajax with MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, knockout.js

This is My KnockOut Controller Class

```
public class KnockoutController : Controller
   {
    //
    // GET: /Knockout/
    private DataLayer data;
    public KnockoutController()
    {
    data=new DataLayer();
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Grid()
    {
    ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();

    List<Category> categories = data.RetrivingCategories();

    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
    rows.Add(new { Id = category.Id, cell = new object[] { category.Id,        
    category.Name } });
    }

    var jsonData = new
    {
    rows
    };

    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    }
```

And This is My Index View

```
 @{
 ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<title></title>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table">
<tr>
<th>
Key
</th>
<th>
Value
</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: lookupCollection">
<tr>
<td data-bind="text: Key"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Value"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
viewModel = {
lookupCollection: ko.observableArray()
};

$(function () {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "@Url.Action("Grid", "Knockout")",
}).done(function (data) {
$(data).each(function (index, element) {
var mappedItem =
{
Id: ko.observable(element.id),
Key: ko.observable(element.name),
};
viewModel.lookupCollection.push(mappedItem);
});
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}).error(function (ex) {
alert("Error");
});
});
</script>``
```

I am Calling json data from this index view using ajax call method but it's not returning anything, Any problem on my Script Part, Please help me , i am new to the Knockout..

Comment: In the ajax 'done' condition, are you able to see that the data parameter has data in it?

Comment: no it's not hitting the ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("Grid","Knockout")",
    }).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, element) {
            var mappedItem = {
                Id: ko.observable(element.id),
                Key: ko.observable(element.name),
            };
            viewModel.lookupCollection.push(mappedItem);
        });
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    }).error(function (ex) {
        alert("Error");
    });
});
```

From the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/),

> The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is
>   used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each()
>   function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array.